# Can SSIS output an SQL Server Compact 4.0 file?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I am using SSIS 2008 to read data from my database. Now I would like it to save that data in an SQL Server Compact 4.0 file (which will be read by the ASP.net MVC 3 app)

Has anyone else done this?

Like I said this is for a SQL CE 4.0, not 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SQL Server Compact Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140269.aspx) component in a data flow.

Answer (score 0):

you have a component specially to do this:

[image]